# Filamentphp v3 : Access other field value for store at relationship form

Tags: php, laravel, filamentphp

cannot access article field when update publish table, article field need for data in publish field.
it try with mutateRelationshipDataBeforeSaveUsing(), but not able to access article field.

or have any approach for the problem?

```
return $form
  ->schema([
    Group::make([
      Section::make('article')
        ->schema([
          TextInput::make('title'),
          FileUpload::make('thumbnail'),
          RichEditor::make('content'),
        ]),

      Section::make('published')
        ->relationship('published')
        ->schema([
          DatePicker::make('publish_date'),
          Radio::make('edited_status')
            ->options([
              'drafted' => 'drafted',
              'completed' => 'completed',
              'archived' => 'archived',
            ]),
          Radio::make('publish_status')
            ->options([
              'queue' => 'queue',
              'preview' => 'preview',
              'publish' => 'publish'
            ]),
        ])
        ->mutateRelationshipDataBeforeCreateUsing(function (array $data, Model $record): array {
          // work on create
          $edited_history = [
            'title' => $record['title'],
            'content' => $record['content'],
            'thumbnail' => $record['thumbnail'],
          ];
          $data['edited_history'] = $edited_history;
          return $data;
        })
        ->mutateRelationshipDataBeforeSaveUsing(function (array $data, Model $record): array {
          // not work on update

          // can't access $data['title']

          $edited_history = [
            'title' => $record['title'],
            'content' => $record['content'],
            'thumbnail' => $record['thumbnail'],
          ];

          //  i want merge and store as json for history

          $data['edited_history'] = $edited_history;
          return $data;
        })
    ]),
  ]);
```

cannot access $data['title'] at mutateRelationshipDataBeforeSaveUsing() function
or any approach for this?